# How to 'recompute' the width of elements in a Materialize row after dynamically inserting an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, grid-layout

I'm trying to write a jQuery script which moves an `input` and its corresponding `label` outside of its parent `div` and places if after, in a separate `div`:

```js
    $("input[id*='-clear_id']").add("label[for*='-clear_id']").wrapAll("<div class='clear-button-wrapper'/>")
    $('.clear-button-wrapper').parent().after($('.clear-button-wrapper'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
  <form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
      <label class="active" for="id_headshot">Headshot</label>
      <div class="btn">
        <span>File</span>
        Currently: <a href="https://lucy-dev2.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/IMG_3515.png">IMG_3515.png</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="headshot-clear" id="headshot-clear_id" />
<label for="headshot-clear_id">Clear</label><br />
Change:
<input type="file" name="headshot" id="id_headshot" />
        
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

What I notice, however, is that the element after that, the `div` with the class `file-path-wrapper`, gets moved down because it no longer fits in the `<div class="row">` (note how the underline no longer aligns with the bottom of the button):

[image]

I've also seen similar behavior with other content that is dynamically added to Materialize tables. It seems like Materialize computes the width of each element 'upfront', and does not adjust the width to accommodate block elements added dynamically later.

Ideally, I'd like to call something like `Materialize.refresh()` to recompute the width of the elements with the newly inserted content. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this particular problem, I finally just added the class `'right'` to the `wrapAll` argument. This makes the 'Clear' input float to the right and everything fits on one row again:

```js
    $("input[id*='-clear_id']").add("label[for*='-clear_id']").wrapAll("<div class='clear-button-wrapper right'/>")
    $('.clear-button-wrapper').parent().after($('.clear-button-wrapper'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    
  <form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
      <label class="active" for="id_headshot">Headshot</label>
      <div class="btn">
        <span>File</span>
        Currently: <a href="https://lucy-dev2.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/IMG_3515.png">IMG_3515.png</a>
<input type="checkbox" name="headshot-clear" id="headshot-clear_id" />
<label for="headshot-clear_id">Clear</label><br />
Change:
<input type="file" name="headshot" id="id_headshot" />
        
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
```

Here is how the result looks:

[image]